# there was no connection string found in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, deployment, connection-string, publish

I am fairly new to ASP.NET and I have encounted the following problem whilst attempting to publish my application. When I click on the "Package/Publish SQL" button and then proceed to try import database entries from my web.config file I get an error that reads "There was no connection string found in the web.config"

As you can see there is connection in my my Web.config

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>   <!--<clear/>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>-->
    <add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=mydatabase\SqlExpress; database=AssetManager.Models.AssetManagerContext; Integrated Security=SSPI " />
  </connectionStrings>




  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Calendar/Index?showLogin=1" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="AssetManagerMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AssetManagerMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile inherits="AssetManager.Models.ProfileModel" defaultProvider="AssetManagerProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AssetManagerProfileProvider" type="System.web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="nathandavies.markdrummond@email.com">
        <network
          host="smtp.gmail.com"
          port="587"
          password="!password"
          userName="nathandavies.markdrummond@email.com"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: just asking. Why add <clear/> <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/> ? Any special reason?

Comment: The remove was put in place by colleague. His rationale for placing the line is to clear up the defaults and ensure the proper settings are used.

Comment: So did you try by commenting it in the .config? Did it work after removing?

Comment: I have just tried to take out the line, and I get the following message when I "import from Web.config". "Web.config file could not be read successfully. This may happen if the web.config is not in a valid state currently."

Comment: Can you share the changes, please? Edit the code in question that is.

Comment: Hi ebad86 I have made the changes in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your connection string on following lines:

**For Sql Server Authentication:**

```
<connectionStrings>   
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=AssetManager.Models.AssetManagerContext;User ID=yourusername;password=yourpassword"           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>   
</connectionStrings>
```

Enter UserName and Password in the corresponding attributes.

**For Windows Authentication**

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="LocalSqlServer"  
connectionString="Data Source="localhost"; 
Initial Catalog=AssetManager.Models.AssetManagerContext;Integrated Security=True" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I still get the same error "Web.config file could not be read successfully. This may happen if the web.config is not in a valid state currently." when I use the SQL server authentication method, I am using SQL server 2008.